# Borehole system running on inverter

Tags: electrical, battery, inverter

3kVA 240V inverter and three gel batteries 100Ah 12V. And I am only running my borehole system 1st pump .38kW, 2nd pump .75kW.

The inverter lasts for five mins then goes off because of low battery.

Comment: What cabling do you have? How is things connected? Three 12V batteries doesn't make 24V.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Also post the age of the batteries, and if older, approximately how many times they were recharged and what device they powered before. And post the voltage of the pumps. Model number of the inverter would be helpful too,

Comment: See this answer for some ideas that may be pertinent: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/258704/140350

Comment: Also this question & answer https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/200987/battery-backup-for-240v-usa-water-well?rq=1